# how to $geoWithin query using "MultiPoint" type?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, 2dsphere

I have the following document in the `myCollection` collection at MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e9176541a4e22ac83afcec"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                40.0, 
                40.848447
            ], 
            [ 
                34.34, 
                38.847
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to find coordinates in bounding box also I know that if coordinates type was "Point" I can query with $box As follows:

```
db.myCollection.find({
   location: { 
        $geoWithin: { 
            $box:  [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 100, 100 ] ] } }
} )
```

but because I have an array of points $box not support from "MultiPoint" type.

so how to query with "MultiPoint" type ?

In addition I don't want use of  $geoIntersects This is not my answer question.